# Create a hardcopy of file and leave original file untouched

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file called `testing`. The file consists of the following simple spreadsheet:

```
     A          B         C        D
1  Revenue    5.000
2  Costs     -4.000
3  Profit     1.000 =SUM(B1:B2)
4
5
```

Now I want to create a hardcopy of this spreadsheet on the desktop. Therefore, I go with this VBA:

```
Sub Create_Hardcopy()
Call Hardcopy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Testing-HC.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Testing-HC.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False
End Sub


Sub Hardcopy()
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Cells.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next I
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far. The hardcopy is created and the original file is closed.

---

However, this code also hardcopies the values in my original sheet but my idea is to keep the original file untouched. Therefore, I used the line `ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False` but somehow it still saves the changes in my original file.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: You get that a 'hardcopy' (*aka* [hard copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_copy)) is one or more printed pieces of paper representing an electronic file don't you? It isn't a workbook where all ,of the formulas have been resolved to their return values. (*source:* [US Federal Standard 1037C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Standard_1037C))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that the syntax in

```
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False
```

is wrong and must be

```
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Note the `:=` instead of `=`.

---

Alternatively do it the other way round.

1. SaveCopy
2. Open the copy
3. "Hardcopy" the copy
4. Close original workbook

So you end up with something like this

```
Public Sub CreateConstantWorkbookCopy()
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Testing-HC.xlsm"

    Dim WbCopy As Workbook
    Set WbCopy = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Testing-HC.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False)

    ReplaceAllFormulasWithValues WbCopy

    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub


Public Sub ReplaceAllFormulasWithValues(wb As Workbook)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        wb.Worksheets(i).Cells.Copy
        wb.Worksheets(i).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the additional alternative code.